# Ubuntu 22.04 login loop, Failed to start GNOME Display Manager

Tags: gnome, permissions, login, services

I'm facing an issue with my Ubuntu system. GNOME Display Manager fails to start at boot and I am unable to login into another tty. Any attempt to login will get me back to credentials prompt.

The only way to get into a terminal is through recovery mode -> root shell. When I try to do a `systemctl start gdm3` in the root shell I get the following error:

> dconf: error while loading shared libraries: libdconf.so.1: cannot open shared object files: Permission denied

There are some other services which also fail before gdm. All of them are failing with a Permission denied error.

These services are:

> systemd-timesyncd.service: Failed to execute /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd: Permission denied

> systemd-timesyncd.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd: Permission denied

Similar to the timesyncd.service I found the following services to fail with the same "Permission denied" reason as the above:

- kerneloops
- systemd-oomd
- xdrp.service

Also, maybe it would be helpful to say what I was doing on the system when the problems started. I was following [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/ucf/text/UCF_Prerequisites.html) installation guide and I was at the "Install Containerd" step and at one point, after executing one of the last commands(I don't remember exactly which one) my gnome interface seemed to fail, all my terminals died and after I tried to reboot, I got to the current state.

Logs seem to point to a permissions problem but I have no idea how to solve it. I really apreciate any advice on how to solve the issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: sounds like you might have multiple issues. What I would do as an interim fix, would be to install lightdm. or some other display manager. What does `startx` do from your root shell?

Comment: `xinit: giving up

xinit: unable to connect to x server: Connection refused

xinit: server error`

The Xorg.0.log file ends with:
`Fatal server error: Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs for all framebuffer devices.`

Also from the Xorg log file, a few lines up from the fatal error there is this line which may or not be related to the last error:
`Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.`

Comment: try "sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target"

Comment: `sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target`
Tried this, it just hangs and the shell becomes unresponsive.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. I managed to solve the issue, posted an answer down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix the issue. Problem was that the permissions to the /usr folder were not 755, as they should be, and other users except root were unable to access it.

Found this issue when I tried to create a new user from the recovery root shell and when I tried to do a `su (new_user)` I got the following error:
`su: failed to execute /bin/bash: Permission denied`.

I guess one of the go to solutions when having permission issues is checking the permissions to your /, /usr and /lib folders.

Good luck!